# База данных

Tags: php, mysql

всем доброго времени суток, как сделать чтобы например при покупке машины чтобы он хранился в базе, потом при 2 покупке машины куда его сохранить , чтобы 1 машина сохранилась, просто чтобы новая машина тоже добавилась?? помогите!

Comment: что это за набор слов вообще?

Comment: У данного товарища почти все вопросы такие :)

Comment: не знаешь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю:
Есть база для хранения покупок (машин) клиентов. Например:

> id | клиент | машина | дата

Судя по всему, ты добавляешь запись о покупке с помощью [INSERT](http://www.sql.ru/docs/mysql/rus_ref/sql.shtml#Insert). Ну так и добавляй туда новую запись при новой покупке. И будет у тебя уже две записи для этого клиента. Они не будут заменять друг друга.

Comment: Только id должен быть auto_increment и не должен быть указан в инсерте (null)